# File manager that bookmarks files

Tags: file-manager

I am using Lubuntu 16 and I need to bookmark files. Which file manager is able to do so?

Note 1 : Lubuntu's default file manager(PCmanFM) doesn't have this feature.

Note 2 : I want to bookmark a file not a folder.

Answer (score 1):

Among its other capabilities, [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) is a file manager (`M-x dired`). While emacs has a substantial learning curve, it can serve as a useful tool for file management (and more...).

To bookmark a file (in the sense that I think you mean), you can open up the directory of interest with dired (`M-x dired`), move to the file of interest and then "bookmark" the file with `C-x r m`. If you with to return to the directory and to that particular file later, you can do so with `C-x r b`.

You can take it a step further: the bookmarking facilities of emacs allow the user to bookmark not only a file but the position in the file as well.

Probably the most useful key bindings to start with are:

`C-x r m` sets a bookmark at the current location

`C-x r b` moves to the location specified by the bookmark

`C-x r l` lists your bookmarks

Comment: What do you mean by C-x r m? is it a comibination of keys as a command?

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. `C-x r m` represents a series of "key presses" which emacs interprets and then invokes the command to which that key sequence maps. `C-x r m` represents pressing the "Control" key at the same time as the "x" key, then releasing those and pressing the r key, then releasing the r key and pressing the m key. (Apologies for the slow response...)